# How can I fetch the order currency in WooCommerce with HPOS compatibility?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce project and facing an issue with fetching the correct currency for orders when High Performance Order Storage (HPOS) is enabled. My goal is to retrieve the currency specifically from the WooCommerce edit order page. Currently, my code returns the default currency set in WooCommerce settings, not the actual currency of the individual order.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\OrderUtil;

    public static function getDefaultLabels(): array {
        $defaultCurrency = self::shouldUseAdminOrderCurrency() ? self::getAdminOrderCurrency() : get_woocommerce_currency();
        $currencyInfo = self::getCurrencyInfo($defaultCurrency);

        $dollarLabel = $currencyInfo['dollar_label'] ?? 'Dollar';
        $centLabel = $currencyInfo['cent_label'] ?? 'Cent';

        return [$dollarLabel, $centLabel];
    }

    private static function shouldUseAdminOrderCurrency(): bool {
        return is_admin() && isset($_GET['post']) && get_post_type($_GET['post']) === 'shop_order';
    }

    private static function getAdminOrderCurrency($order): string {
        if (OrderUtil::custom_orders_table_usage_is_enabled()) {
            $order_id = get_the_ID();
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            return $order->get_currency();
        } else {
            global $post;
            $order_id = $post->ID;
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            return $order->get_currency();
        }
    }

    private static function getCurrencyInfo(string $currencyCode): array {
        $currencyData = self::getCurrencyData();
        return $currencyData[$currencyCode] ?? [];
    }

    private static function getCurrencyData(): array {
        $labels = ['dollar_label', 'cent_label'];
        return [
            'USD' => ['Dollar', 'Cent'],
        ];
    }
```

Despite this implementation, the function returns the default WooCommerce currency instead of the actual currency of the order. Could anyone suggest what might be going wrong or how to ensure compatibility with HPOS to fetch the correct currency from the WooCommerce order? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your provided code doesn't allow to answer your question… Where are you using `getAdminOrderCurrency($order)` function… See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I update the code. Can you please check again?

Comment: I will check that…